# Can I use other tables in database with single model cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any way in `cakephp` where I can use (insert delete update) tables data without creating controller files and view folder.

I have table user with controller `usercontroller.php`.

Can I use one model to use (insert delete update in) other table's data instead of making individual files of controller and view folder for each table?

Comment: @AliNfr: thanks for wanting to improve posts. Backticks ("inline code") are fine for actual code, I/O, filenames etc, but ordinary proper nouns ("PHP", "CakePHP", etc) do not need formatting as code. Formatting of this kind will likely be fixed in subsequent edits. Getting the case right of these is sufficient, imo.

Comment: You need to save data in related models / db table, for example, user edit their profile from UsersController::edit() / edit.ctp ?

Comment: Then you would have to execute sql code manually.
`$this->User->query("SELECT * FROM",false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah sorry, got you wrong.
Try this in your Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('YourModel');
$this->YourModel->create();
$data = array('id' => 123, 'name' => 'Joe');
$this->YourModel->save($data);
```